# Is it possible to interpolate missing frames in video editing?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

Sometimes it is useful to render a complete video even though some (possibly random) frames are still missing.
Is there any way to [interpolate the missing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_interpolation) frames with Blender?
In the case that it is not possible, I would be happy for any suggestion on that problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blender does not currently support inter frame effects that allow information from one frame to inform a later one. What you need is Optical Flow technology.  There are a number of software solutions available and even some free ones, depending on your OS.

This would be a neat trick for blender however, allowing you to render at half frame rate then interpolate the rest.

Comment: it would be great for footage which needs to be slowed down a lot.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using proprietary software for this task. But as you said, such a feature could be very helpful!

Comment: It would be nice to work around cache limitations after building a big physic sim, you cannot slow those down without rebaking.